# Bitcoin PHP JSONRPC permission denied

Tags: php, json, bitcoind

After reading https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/API_reference_(JSON-RPC)#PHP and also other tutorials, i haven't gotten it to work. All the JSON RPC libraries i use return the same error:

> 4.81.94:8332/): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/html/v2/jsonRPCClient.php on line 132

I also tried easybitcoin.php found on Github that one shows nothing but a blank page.

HOWEVER, when i run the command in SSH, it works perfectly.

> bitcoin-cli getinfo

works in SSH and also

> php bt.php

also works but when i run this in browser like http://ipaddress/bt.php all i get is a blank page(Using easybitcoin.php) or Permission Denied(Using JsonRPC)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using your username and password define int the bitcoin.conf file that should resolve your problem